# How to remove Gstreamer plugin from the blacklist?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

When running `gst-inspect-1.0 libgstkvssink.so`

I am getting that my so is blacklisted.

```
Plugin Details:
  Name                     libgstkvssink.so
  Description              Plugin for blacklisted file
  Filename                 /home/laptop-obs-65/kinesis/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/build/libgstkvssink.so
  Version                  0.0.0
  License                  BLACKLIST
  Source module            BLACKLIST
  Binary package           BLACKLIST
  Origin URL               BLACKLIST


  0 features:
```

To check the reasons for this, I set `GST_DEBUG=4` and removed `.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.x86_64.bin` file.

After re-running, getting these warnings

```
0:00:00.008126332 27286 0x561c51508400 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:484:gst_plugin_register_func: plugin "/home/laptop-obs-65/kinesis/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/build/libgstkvssink.so" has incompatible version (plugin: 1.18, gst: 1,16), not loading

0:00:00.180073959 27286 0x561c51508400 WARN                  ladspa gstladspa.c:507:plugin_init:<plugin69> no LADSPA plugins found, check LADSPA_PATH


:00:00.233548719 27286 0x561c51508400 WARN                 default gstsf.c:97:gst_sf_create_audio_template_caps: format 0x120000: 'AVR (Audio Visual Research)' is not mapped
0
```

Gstreamer version

**gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.18.4**

**GStreamer 1.16.2**

How can I remove the .so plugin and its dependencies from the blacklist? Is this a version issue?

Answer (score 0):

You usually delete the registry cache so on the next init the plugins undergo a full scan again. That is fine.

And yes, this is a version issue. You have a plugin compiled with a newer version of GStreamer than you are are trying to run against. This will be rejected, the other way round would be okay.